Filter AppMenuItem by NamespacePrefix
I want to get a list of all apps that were created in an org. So I would filter all AppMenuItem objects by NamespacePrefix, like so:
SELECT NamespacePrefix, Name
FROM AppMenuItem
WHERE NamespacePrefix = NULL
ORDER BY NamespacePrefix, Name

Interestingly this will return all the standard Salesforce apps as well:

The NamespacePrefix seems to be treated like a null value even though it returns standard.
Any idea why? What is going on here? I tested this in two different production orgs and NULL will not filter standard for whatever reason.

When I tried this query in my org then no standard value returned. See this: https://tinyurl.com/27q3j9aq
Also, as per the documentation, If you are using the developer org then make sure that you have not created any namespace prefix of the org. If your org is other then developer org then NamespacePrefix will be null.

Very interesting. It's not a dev org but a production org. Do you not have any entries with a NamespacePrefix that has the value standard by any means? Maybe that explains the difference.

Yes I have standard entries see this: https://tinyurl.com/233xs4ka

How odd. When I run the query above I will also get the standard entries.

When I am filtering the AppMenuItem with NamespacePrefix = NULL then no standard or other prefix data is returned.  https://tinyurl.com/27q3j9aq But if I removed the filter then all records return with standard records https://tinyurl.com/233xs4ka

Weird. There must be a difference between our orgs then. I tested this in two production orgs and it always yielded the same result. See my updated question for an example.

The above screenshot is from the developer edition. I have tried the same query in the enterprise edition and then returned the result the same as yours. see. https://tinyurl.com/27f5gxoy I think the reason behind this is there is no namespace registered in this enterprise edition. I suggested that you create a case with the salesforce and validate the reason for this weird query output.
